# implicit conversion of one HList to another

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a use case in my library where an `HList A` is considered convertible to `HList B` if it **contains** all the elements of `HList B` **regardless** of ordering. I need there to be an implicit conversion between the two such as this:

```
// implicit arguments omitted for readability
implicit def toOther[A <: HList, B <: HList](l: A): B = l.filter[B].align[B]
```

but `HList.filter` returns `HNil` if supplied with a type argument of type HList. how else can I convert A to B?

**Edit**

Here is an attempt to implement the functionality In case you need boiler plate to copy and paste:

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Align

implicit def toOther[A <: HList, B <: HList](v: A)(implicit a: Align[A, B]): B = v.align[B]

def method(p: Int :: Boolean :: HNil): Unit = println("success")

val list = false :: 7 :: HNil

// works on it's own. (only for Hlists of same length though)
toOther[Boolean :: Int :: HNil,Int :: Boolean :: HNil](list)

//doesn't work! Weird!
// also if it did, it only would for two HLists of the same length
method(list)
```

Comment: I think the implicit parameters are actually pretty important for this question.

Comment: @Jasper-M well we know my method doesn't work. but yeah if it did, ```(implicit a: Align[A, B], f: Filter[A,B])```  would have been the imports from ```shapeless.ops.hlist.{ Align, Filter}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the conversion part, I think what you're looking for is the `SelectAll` typeclass. As to why the conversion doesn't kick in implicitly I'm not sure yet. It seems in the case that both the expected and the actual type are known like in your  example the compiler has enough information to pick `toOther`.

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.SelectAll

implicit def toOther[A <: HList, B <: HList](a: A)(implicit convert: SelectAll[A,B]): B = convert(a)
```

Comment: aligning doesn't work apparently if the length of the HLists are not equal.

Comment: also interestingly I tried your exact implementation with two equally sized HLists. but for some weird reason the conversion won't be triggered by the compiler where it should. it throws a type mismatch error. intellij interface doesn't complain though...

Comment: @shayan you also want to convert A to B if A contains extra elements? As for your second comment, that's strange. I can't look into it further right now though. To be continued.

Comment: yes I do. also I've edited my question adding all failing example cases

Comment: @shayan I updated my answer. I'll think about the implicit conversion part some more.

Comment: thank you. after pasting your code the compiler complains that: ```Error:(4, 100) type mismatch;
 found   : convert.Out
 required: B
implicit def toOther[A <: HList, B <: HList](a: A)(implicit convert: SelectMany[A,B]): B = convert(a)
  ^```

Comment: Are you sure that's not Intellij being confused? `convert.Out` and `B` should be the same... I'll take a better look at it later.

Comment: you should have imported the ```SelectAll``` type class :). Also as to why the implicit conversion doesn't trigger although its implemented correctly I would appreciate if you gave it some more thought

Comment: on shapeless 2.3.2 the ```SelectAll[A,B]#Out``` is equal to ```B``` which is exactly what I need. How ever the ```SelectMany[A,B]#Out``` is still abstract apparently... can't see what's happening anyway...

Comment: Yes you're right. I looked at the wrong `Out`. Don't know if there is a difference in semantics between both typeclasses other than that one loses type information...